# Async Behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I have the following code to update the progress bar in async fashion and i notice 
its async behaviour through the call to MessageBox.In this case it works perfectly
but when i give a sleep of 1s(1000) the MessageBox doesnot pops up and the the complete progress bar fills at once.
Kindly tell why this is happening.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Update_Async async = new Update_Async(Update_Async_method);
        progressBar1.BeginInvoke(async,10);
        MessageBox.Show("Updation In Progress");


    }

    public void Update_Async_method(int a)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = a;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = a;
            Thread.Sleep(10);

     //Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
```

Comment: try 'progressBar1.value=i' not a. If you set it to a, you set it to complete.

Comment: So, which bit happens asynchronously, i.e. on another thread? When you call `BeginInvoke` on a control, the code is invoked on the main GUI thread. The main GUI thread is where you're `Click` event handler is already running. Hence, no asynchronicity.

Comment: So for what reason we have BeginInvoke On Controls.Please Elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Update_Async.BeginInvoke(async, 10)` instead if you want the delegate to run asynchrnously but, you'll have to cross thread checking on the update to the progress bar.

---

In response to your comment, very similar to what you are doing already,

```
void UpdatingFunction(int value)
{
    if (this.progressBar.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.progressBar.BeginInvoke(UpdatingFunction, value);
        return;
    }

    // Invoke not required, work on progressbar. 
}
```

This also explains what the `Invoke` methods on controls are for.

Comment: And how can i do that checking ?Please Elaborate

Answer (score 0):

`Delegate.BeginInvoke` will run a method in a thread once and then dispose it. It is a poor choice if you want to repeatedly do some work in a thread and return intermediate results. If that is what you want, you should use `BackgroundWorker`. Highly abbreviated snippet:

```
BackgroundWorker bw;

YourFormConstructor()
{
    ...
    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += BackgroundCalculations;
    bw.ProgressChanged += ShowBackgroundProgress;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bw.RunWorkerAsync(10);
}

void ShowBackgroundProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

static void BackgroundCalculations(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    int max = (int)e.Argument;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        bw.ReportProgress(i * 100 / max);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    bw.ReportProgress(100);
    }
}
```